# Regular Expression to Match Past Label Including Empty String

Tags: regex

Using a regular expression, I'm trying to match a label, in this case "Business Unit:", followed by one or more spaces, then match everything in a submatch after that to the end of that line.  I'm having a problem when there are no characters after the label on the line, it grabs the next line.

For example, here's some test data:

```
Business Unit:(space)(space)BU1(space)
This is Line 2
Business Unit:(space)(space)
This is Line 4
```

So I want to grab just "BU1" from the first line, and that works.  It should match an empty string from the third line, but it matches the contents of the fourth line instead, in this case "This is Line 4".

Here is my expression:

```
Business Unit:\s+(.+)
```

I thought the dot character is **not** suppose to match a newline, but it seems like it is.

What's the correct regular expression in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that `\s+` is greedy, so it will match all whitespace (including new lines), so it matches up until the next line and then `.+` catches the rest.

[This should meet your requirements](https://regex101.com/r/lLpayR/2).

The pattern is `^Business Unit: *([\S]*)`

This is assuming of course your business unit won't contain any spaces. If it does, then I can modify the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, a bit on the context you are using the regex in because multi-line handling may vary, but here is a start:

```
/^Business Unit: +([^ ]*) *$/
```

1. `^` Starting from the beginning of the line,
2. Match the literal, `Business Unit:`,
3. `+` followed by 1 or more spaces,
4. `([^ ]*)` capture any possible non-blank stuff,
5. `*$` followed by spaces till the end of the line.

Again, depending on your context, you may need to specify the linend as `\n`:

```
/^Business Unit: +([^ ]*) *\n/
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` character is part of `\s`. That is why you get a match onto the following line.

You can do:

```
/^Business Unit:[ \t]*([^\n]*?)[ \t]*$/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3oyYX/3/)

If you want to exclude the leading horizontal spaces and not match if blank:

```
/^Business Unit:[ \t]+(\S+)[ \t]*$/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3oyYX/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class *substraction* for whitespace *except* newlines:

```
Business Unit:[\s&&[^\n]]*(\S*)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/9mJRy8G1hx).

The expression `[\s&&[^\n]]` is the subtraction, then the capture is for 0 or more non-whitespace (your target).

Answer (score 0):

In your example you capture the last line because [\s](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) also matches a newline.

What you could do is replace `\s+` to a whitespace  and capture in a group any character zero or more times `.*`

You might use a word boundary `\b` at the start.

[`\bBusiness Unit: +(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/w59J9u/1)

**Update**

Bases on the comments, to not match whitespace at the end of the line you could use match one or more times a non whitespace characters `\S+` followed by repeated pattern  that matches a whitespace or a tab `[ \t]` and one or more times a non whitespace character and make the group optional `?`

[`\bBusiness Unit: +(\S+(?:[ \t]\S+)*)?`](https://regex101.com/r/kp2KlG/1)

Comment: Ah, I thought \s only matched a space or tab.  Given subsequent answers, I now have the following expression: Business Unit:[ \t]*(.*)[ \t]*  But the .* is grabbing trailing whitespace, which I want to eliminate.  How can I do that?  Note that the value to be matched CAN have embedded spaces (along with special chars).  For example, "Central System (CS)".

Comment: @JoeA Do you mean like [`\bBusiness Unit: +(\S+(?:[ \t]\S+)*)?`](https://regex101.com/r/kp2KlG/1) which matches non whitespace characters using `\S` followed by a repeating pattern that matches a whitespace or a tab followed by non whitespace characters so that will not match a whitespace at the end.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.

Comment: @JoeA You are welcome. I have added that as an update to my answer.